# [APPIUM WINAPP DRIVER[ BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported

Tags: c#, appium, specflow, winappdriver

Tech Stack: C#, SpecFlow, WinAppDriver, Nunit [Test Runner]

Scenario:

This is an Automation Test project where I need to integrate parallel testing using Selenium grid architecture. I have setup HUB and NODE and when I try to run multiple test cases [Say 2] I get the below exception.

---

### **BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Multiple public constructors with the same maximum parameter count are not supported**

Stack Trace:

**----> BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported! OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver`1[[OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsElement, Appium.Net, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
Stack Trace:
RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
ObjectContainer.CreateObject(Type type, ResolutionList resolutionPath, RegistrationKey keyToResolve)
TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name)
TestObjectResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer container) line 11
lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , String )
BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) line 70
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments) line 20
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 100
TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep() line 21
TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors() line 78**

Hooks Class File

```
public Hooks(ScenarioContext sc){
  this.sc = sc;
  this.objectContainer = sc.ScenarioContainer.ObjectContainer;
}
 
 [BeforeScenario]
 public InitializeWinAppDriver(){
   this.webDriver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>("{uri of Hub}","{appium options}");
   objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>>(webDriver);
   }
```

Step Class
private LoginUi loginUiObj;

```
public LoginStep(ScenarioContext sc){
 this.WebDriver = sc.ObjectContainer.Resolve<WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>>();
 this.loginUiObj - new LogionUi(WebDriver);
}
```

UI Element Class

```
  private WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> winAppDriver   
   public LoginUi(WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> driver) =>  winAppDriver = driver;
```

I have Feature File when I run the test case I get the above exception.

Comment: The only thing that I can think about what is triggering this exception is, that the LoginStep constructor is called before the InitializeWinAppDriver hook.

Comment: @AndreasWillich hooks class constructor will be called first where we initialize scenario context, object container and feature context and later we have [BeforeFeature] & [BeforeScenario] attributes where we initialize WinAppDriver and register in object container.  Once these steps are completed the flow move to FeatureFile where the test cases are written and LoginSteps constructor is called. Here I don't think LoginSteps constructor is called before the InitializeWindappDriver hook. The problem occurs when parallel testing is performed. It would be great if you can help me to figure it out

Comment: Does it work if you don't run the scenarios in parallel?

Comment: Yes it works when i dont run in parallel

Comment: Then you need to create an issue at https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.

Comment: Sure Will do that thanks @AndreasWillich.